# OpenCV Python SIFT Faster than C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, sift

I'm working on trying to detect features with OpenCV. I'm using the SIFT algorithm built into OpenCV. I tried testing code with both the Python and C++ versions of OpenCV, and for some reason the Python version is much faster. I don't understand why the C++ version is so much slower. Shouldn't they be similar speeds?

My Python code essentially goes as follows:

```
img1 = cv2.imread(image1Path, 0)
img2 = cv2.imread(image2Path, 0)
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
print(time.clock())
kp1,des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2,des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
print(time.clock())
```

My C++ code is as follows:

```
Mat img1 = imread(image1Path, 0)
Mat img2 = imread(image2Path, 0)
Ptr<SIFT> sift = SIFT::create();

std::vector<KeyPoint> img1_keypoints;
Mat img1_descriptors;
std::vector<KeyPoint> img2_keypoints;
Mat img2_descriptors;

double freq = getTickFrequency();
int64 start = getTickCount();
sift->detectAndCompute(img1, Mat(), img1_keypoints, img1_descriptors);
sift->detectAndCompute(img2, Mat(), img2_keypoints, img2_descriptors);
int64 end = getTickCount();
double time = (end - start) / freq;
cout << "Time: " << time << endl;
```

One of my images is fairly large, resulting in about 80,000 features being found in img2. When I check the time that it takes to run, the Python code takes about 5 seconds. When I try the C++ code, it takes about 20 seconds. The code is pretty much the same, and my timing code only surrounds the detectAndCompute() functions, so it's pretty much only OpenCV that is being timed.

For C++, I'm using OpenCV 3.4.5. For Python, I'm using OpenCV-python 3.4.2. I don't think these versions should have a huge difference though, so I'm really not sure what the problem could be.

Edit:
As suggested by the comments, I tried compiling and running my C++ program in release mode. It runs in about 3-4 seconds now, so I think that is the issue.

Just as heads up to people who might have the same problem as me, when I changed my program from debug to release mode in Visual Studio 2017, I was getting a memory access error with the class std::vector on the line:

```
sift->detectAndCompute(img1, Mat(), img1_keypoints, img1_descriptors);
```

I solved the problem by going into the properties for my project, Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies and removing "opencv_world345d.lib" from the configuration. You need "opencv_world345.lib" instead when running in release mode.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: What oprimization compiler flags did you use when compiling the c++ code?

Comment: Do you mean when I built the OpenCV library or when I build the project and run it? I'm using Visual Studio, and I am clicking on the "Build" button and running with the "Start debugging" option.

Comment: So you're benchmarking a debug build? You should make a release build and measure again.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what my issue was.